# How do large PHP applications like Wordpress, Joomla, vBulletin run so fast?

Tags: php

If you think about it, all of the applications I mentioned have tens of thousands of lines of side, some hundreds of thousands. Yet they seem to have a fairly light footprint despite the huge amounts of code that must be run through the PHP interpreter for each and every request.

Why is that?

Comment: Why do think they run extra large amount of code each request?

Comment: In my experience, none of those applications have a light footprint. A wordpress requests eats up north of 12 MB RAM each time if it's got a few plugins installed. I'm fairly sure Joomla and vBulletin are no better.

Comment: only a small set of files are interpreted based on request

Comment: C or C++ languages with many more lines can run faster relatively. I do not think those applications require much of cpu-intense calculations which can be run fast.

Comment: @Pekka: They're not light, but at least fast.

Comment: What, you think those are fast? They have a snail pace compared to custom code specific to the problem only. But simply put: of those 'hundreds of thousands' of lines, only a very small portion is actually read/needed for a single request, and a few thousand can be read/interpreted relatively quick, even more so with a cache like APC.

Comment: @genesis well, depending on the server resources available of course - I know old servers where a modern Wordpress takes a second to respond

Comment: Joomla! is slow as torture, on an average server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you think about it, all of the applications I mentioned have tens
>   of thousands of lines of side, some hundreds of thousands.

That's actually fairly small. There are projects out there with millions, even tens of millions of lines of code.

> Yet they seem to have a fairly light footprint despite the huge
>   amounts of code that must be run through the PHP interpreter for each
>   and every request.

Often the code is only parsed once and the resulting bytecode stored in a cache (e.g. Xcahe, APC). So, all those lines do not have to be interpreted every request.

Also, not all the code needs to be executed every request.

Usually, the bulk of the time it takes a web application respond is database access and data transfer (either from the database to PHP, and from PHP though the webserver to your application).

Comment: >That's actually fairly small. There are projects out there with millions, even tens of millions of lines of code. < Example?

Comment: @genesis: Typo3 is about 3-4 times the size of Wordpress. All of Plone + Zope starts to approach a million. Facebook is several million.

Comment: how can you be sure that Facebook has million code lines?

Comment: @genesis: [They said so](http://www.quora.com/How-large-is-Facebooks-codebase) at various places around the internet. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about quantity, but quality. I can read four lines of codes which would take more time to execute than Wordpress page.

It's all about good optimalization

However, those applications you listed aren't light to RAM & CPU usage

Comment: I like first paragraph and you are right, it is not about quantity but quality of the code.

Comment: I thought someone likes it :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that they don't in comparison to other technologies, but compared to how quickly a human could do it: sure, they're fast.

Something else to consider is that the PHP interpreter isn't running through all the code in the Wordpress directory for every request. Apache is going to get it started with a single PHP page which then pulls in other pages on demand. All of those pages are then interpreted on the fly until the program has the results it needs, so sometimes a good bit of the code on a page is not utilized, which keeps the footprint smaller.

Also, depending on the way you're actually running PHP makes a big difference. If you're in one of the CGI modes, each request boots up an instance of the PHP interpreter, whereas PHP as an Apache module has it preloaded into memory already so it doesn't have to do that frontloading.

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally find that they do run fast. It takes almost half a second to render a page on most wordpress sites - yet many of them are on a server with a CPU able to calculate billions of cycles every second.

That's not to say PHP its self is that slow. My applications (built on a framework) generally run in about 50ms using only 3MB of RAM (and only 600kb of that is from my code).